# PHP safe upload system

Tags: php, file, upload, mime-types

So I have this file upload system that is supposed to only accept the file types in $allowedExts but some guy keeps breaching the system with a file called angel.jpg.php. I think he has changed the mime type but I am still wondering how he breached the extension check.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php    
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "doc", "pages", "docx",  "pdf","ppt","pptx","xls","xlsx");

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$extension2 = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/bmp")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-msexcel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && in_array($extension2, $allowedExts) && getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["name"])!=='FALSE')
{
// Upload file
}

else {
// Do not upload file
}
```

Comment: Your logic is flawed, because the conditions for the extension are `&&`-linked to the last of your mime type conditions only, because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. You need to put another set of round brackets around all those `||`-linked conditions.

Comment: try to minimize the logical conditions by putting the $_FILES["file"]["type"] into a variable

Comment: And combining all those none-image mime types with `getimagesize` does not make much sense either – I doubt that `getimagesize` will return anything but `false` if you let it check f.e. an excel document.

Comment: So do I need to look at the file content then?

Comment: Drop all that and replace it with an array and `in_array($realMimeType, $arrayOfAllowedMimeTypes, true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody added more useful tips.
I decided to search for them myself.
I found some pretty good tips on various websites.

Here are two of them:
http://hungred.com/useful-information/secure-file-upload-check-list-php/
http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/